# Film where a preternaturally talented hitman falls in love with a woman with the same skills, but she doesn't know it yet

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this within the last five years, I think on Netflix. We get introduced to a hitman who is extremely talented, able to take down multiple targets without getting injured, and dodging shots before they're fired. Due to a combination of his talent and success rate, either he picks and chooses which contracts he takes, or he's simply freelancing. Either way, I remember his fees often being comically low. There are two plotlines going one. First, for some reason, he's being targeted by other killers during the movie, something he doesn't take seriously at all. Secondly, he meets a girl. I don't remember if it's a blind date, or a chance meeting, but he pursues her in something halfway in between clumsy but sincere nice guy and overly persistent Nice Guy.

What pushes this film into sci-fi for me is that he describes his talent as something extra, some sort of a oneness with the universe such that he knows exactly what to do to complete a task, and when he meets the girl, she has the exact same skill, something which he proves by throwing knives at her and she automatically catches or juggles them, kind of similar to how Merrick proved Buffy's skills in the *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* film. I think that the ultimate resolution of the film is that she accepts that her skills make her an excellent assassin as well, and so they become a team both romantically and professionally.

Other than the knife juggling scene, the only other ones that jump out at me was a scene outside of a bar where he took down a knife-wielding opponent (I think from a former employer unhappy with him?) with light talk in between attacks, I think about having met the girl, and a scene where he and the girl are in a park, and he starts "dancing" with her, foiling the shots of a sniper in the park.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't it, but it's odd that it has so many plot points in common with the 2016/2017 TV version of Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency. (Preternaturally talented people, a girl with special hitman skills, the talents being due to a sort of one-ness with the universe.) That one doesn't have the romance aspect at all though, and the girl is already a hitman when we meet her.

Comment: If the gender roles were reversed, I'd suggest [Wanted](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0493464/).

Comment: Huh. That is true.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is *[Mr. Right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Right_(2015_film))* starring Anna Kendrick and Sam Rockwell. The knife juggling happens in her kitchen. The special ability they seem to have is the ability to read the flow of motion in the world around them, and go with it.

> Ex-CIA agent and ex-mercenary Francis Munch (Rockwell) kills those who try to hire him. On his way out from such a kill, a team including Espinoza (Da Silva) tries to kill Munch; Munch's ex-partner and trainer, Ed Hopper (Roth), quits beforehand but listens as Munch kills them.
>
> Martha McKay (Kendrick) is asked out by Munch, and both grow smitten with each other. Munch dodges an assassination attempt by Espinoza. The two spend the night chastely. The next evening, they meet for dinner, where Munch reluctantly kills Espinoza when confronted. Over hot chocolate, Munch demonstrates to Martha his belief that underlying all physical objects lies a current that can be precognitively anticipated, and that both he and Martha have this. Munch throws a kitchen knife high in the air and catches it safely as it falls between them. This freaks Martha out until he throws a knife at her, which she catches by the blade without being cut. The two then have an intimate night.

....

> Two months later, two military-style teams are pursuing both Munch and Martha as they visit different countries for Martha's paleological interests; Munch turns a sign to the sniper asking "where's the girl?" as the scene cuts to Martha, who has snuck up to shoot the sniper.

Comment: That does look right!

Comment: It's a great movie.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edits. :) I always like to copy over relevant quotes, makes it all the more likely that the answer will show up on subsequent searches.

Comment: Not at all. I don't usually have time to be that thorough, so it's great to have additions like that added to my answers.

Comment: "This freaks Martha out until he throws a knife at her, which she catches by the blade without being cut. The two then have an intimate night." That never worked for me.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer it's a really goofy movie but it makes sense in context.